# Why is my NFT showing as a placeholder image instead of the actual NFT image?

Tags: gnosis-safe

As described in the title. I moved my NFT to the Gnosis Safe. It's showing up, but only with a placeholder image and not the actual NFT image. Why is this happening?

Note: The NFT image is showing correctly on OpenSea.io.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, different NFT contracts wildly vary within the ERC-721/1155 standards.

Metadata, especially, is an open-ended game and marketplaces like OpenSea go to great lengths to support [multiple metadata formats](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards).

I've seen a few collections, like F..cked Up Homers and Zorbs, not showing up correctly in the Safe.

Zorbs, for example, [encode their metadata JSON in a data URI](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/3325). It works on OpenSea, but we think it's outside of Safe's scope to support all the various ways to encode metadata.

You can still view your NFT if you connect your Safe to OpenSea via WalletConnect.

We'll take your question as valuable feedback, though.

Answer (score 1):

I created an NFT collection and witnessed this before as well.

It seems like the Gnosis Safe operated on a schedule and after a day or so it updated with the correct image(s).

This NFT collection abided by the recommended OpenSea metadata standard.